# Get substring in a string with multiple occurring string

Tags: java

I have a string something like

```
(D@01)5(D@02)14100319530033M(D@03)1336009-A-A(D@04)141002A171(D@05)1(D@06)
```

Now i want to get substring between `(D@01)5(D@02)`

If i have something like

```
(D@01)5(D@02)
```

i can get detail with

```
    quantity         = content.substring(content.indexOf("(D@01)") + 6, content.indexOf("(D@02)"));
```

But somethings `D@02` can be different like `@05`, Now how can i use simple `(D@` to get string in between. there are multiple repetitions of `(D@`

Basically this is what i want to do

```
content.substring(content.indexOf("(D@01)") + 6, content.nextOccurringIndexOf("(D@"));
```

Comment: You could use something like `String#split` and pass it `\(D@[0-9]+\)` as the regular expression, this would at least allow you to get the data between the `(@D*)` blocks...

Comment: @MadProgrammer but no indicator showing which one is for 1 or 2 or 3

Comment: Use with this overload of `indexOf` `public int indexOf(String str, int fromIndex);`

Comment: Then use the `Matcher` API which will give more information...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you can do

```
int fromIndex = content.indexOf("(D@01)") + 6;
int toIndex = content.indexOf("(D@", fromIndex);    // next occurring

if (fromIndex != -1 && toIndex != -1)
    str = content.substring(fromIndex, toIndex);
```

**Output**

```
5
```

See http://ideone.com/RrUtBy demo.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the marker and value are some how linked and you want to know each (`(D@01)` == `5`), then you can make use of the `Pattern`/`Matcher` API, for example

```
String text = "(D@01)5(D@02)14100319530033M(D@03)1336009-A-A(D@04)141002A171(D@05)1(D@06)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(D@[0-9]+\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

while (m.find()) {
    String name = m.group();
    if (m.end() < text.length()) {
        String content = text.substring(m.end()) + 1;
        content = content.substring(0, content.indexOf("("));
        System.out.println(name + " = " + content);
    }
}
```

Which outputs

```
(D@01) = 5
(D@02) = 14100319530033M
(D@03) = 1336009-A-A
(D@04) = 141002A171
(D@05) = 1
```

Now, this is a little heavy handed, I'd create some kind of "marker" object which contained the key `(D@01)` and it's start and end indices.  I'd then keep this information in a `List` and cut up each value based on the end of the earlier key and the start of the last key...but that's just me ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex capture groups if want the content between the `(D@##)`'s

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\(D@\\d+\\))(.*?)(?=\\(D@\\d+\\))");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher("(D@01)5(D@02)14100319530033M(D@03)1336009-A-A(D@04)141002A171(D@05)1(D@06)");
while(matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(String.format("%s start: %2s end: %2s matched: %s ",
      matcher.group(1), matcher.start(2), matcher.end(2), matcher.group(2)));
}
```

---

```
(D@01) start:  6 end:  7 matched: 5 
(D@02) start: 13 end: 28 matched: 14100319530033M 
(D@03) start: 34 end: 45 matched: 1336009-A-A 
(D@04) start: 51 end: 61 matched: 141002A171 
(D@05) start: 67 end: 68 matched: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user regex to split the input - as suggested by @MadProgrammer. `split()` method produces a table of `String`s, so the order of the occurrences of the searched values will be exactly the same as the order of the values in the table produced by `split()`. For example:

```
String input = "(D@01)5(D@02)14100319530033M(D@03)1336009-A-A(D@04)141002A171(D@05)1(D@06)";

String[] table = input.split("\(D@[0-9]+\)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "(D@01)5(D@02)14100319530033M(D@03)1336009-A-A(D@04)141002A171(D@05)1(D@06)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(D@\\d+\\)(.*?)(?=\\(D@\\d+\\))");
    Matcher matches = p.matcher(input);
    while(matches.find()) {
        int number = getNum(matches.group(0)); // parses the number
        System.out.printf("%d. %s\n", number, matches.group(1)); // print the string
    }
}

public static int getNum(String str) {
    int start = str.indexOf('@') + 1;
    int end = str.indexOf(')', start);
    return Integer.parseInt(str.substring(start,end));
}
```

Result:

```
1. 5
2. 14100319530033M
3. 1336009-A-A
4. 141002A171
5. 1
```